# Can't bypass optional chaining error using Babel or Webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, aws-sdk, optional-chaining

I am having an issue when I am trying to use the aws-sdk v3.
I am confident it is because of the optional chaining used in this node module file.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist-es/getCanonicalHeaders.js 10:30
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:30)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|         const canonicalHeaderName = headerName.toLowerCase();
|         if (canonicalHeaderName in ALWAYS_UNSIGNABLE_HEADERS ||
>             unsignableHeaders?.has(canonicalHeaderName) ||
|             PROXY_HEADER_PATTERN.test(canonicalHeaderName) ||
|             SEC_HEADER_PATTERN.test(canonicalHeaderName)) {
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist-es/index.js 2:0-60 2:0-60
```

I am using Babel 7, Webpack 4, and Node 14.

I've added `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` to my `babel.config` file below:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'];
  const plugins = [
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator'],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining'],
  ];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
};
```

I've even tried adding `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` to my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx|es)$/,
          use: [
            'thread-loader',
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                plugins: [
                  '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
                  '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining'
                ],
                presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env']
              }
            }
          ],
          exclude: '/node_modules/',
        },
```

Comment: What version of Node are you trying to run this all under? Babel  etc. won't generally transpile dependencies.

Comment: I am using v14.6.0